# Combined linux commands not writing outfile.txt

Tags: linux, awk, sed, cat, tail

I want to search in a log file (real-time) for the contents of msg="yxyxyx" and then write the unique values to outfile.txt

I wrote this:

```
tail -f /var/log/firewall.log | sed -n '/msg=/{s/.*msg=//;s/\S*=.*//;p}' | awk '!seen[$0]++' >> outfile.txt
```

Outfile is created but empty. It's writing perfectly to the console without >> outfile.txt part.

Thank you!

Comment: Posting a few lines of that `firewall.log` would sure help testing.

Comment: The sed command obviously removes everything.

Comment: log sample:
Oct 20 15:23:14 10.1.2.250 id=firewall time="2016-10-20 15:23:14" user="xy" srcif="vlan1" srcifname="vlan_980" ipproto=tcp dstif="vlan0" dstifname="INET_GW" proto=ssl src=1.2.3.4 dst=41.23.93.35 dstname=star-mini.c10r.facebook.com ipv=4 action=pass msg="some message" class=ssl:client classification=0 alarmid=1 logtype="alarm"

and I'd like to write all kind of 'some message' to a separate file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you use stdbuf -oL or stdbuf -o0 before awk command as below;

```
tail -f firewall.log | sed -nu '/msg=/{s/.*msg=//;s/\S*=.*//;p}' | stdbuf -oL awk '!seen[$0]++' >> outfile.txt
```

tail -f firewall.log | sed -nu '/msg=/{s/.*msg=//;s/\S*=.*//;p}' | stdbuf -o0 awk '!seen[$0]++' >> outfile.txt

man sed;

> -u, --unbuffered
>
> load minimal amounts of data from the input files and flush the output
>   buffers more often

man stdbuf;

> stdbuf - Run COMMAND, with modified buffering operations for its
>   standard streams.
>
> -o, --output=MODE
>             adjust standard output stream buffering
>
> If MODE is 'L' the corresponding stream will be line buffered. 
>   This option is invalid with standard input.
>
> If MODE is '0' the corresponding stream will be unbuffered.

Eg;

first run this;

```
user@h$ tail -f firewall.log | sed -nu '/msg=/{s/.*msg=//;s/\S*=.*//;p}' | stdbuf -oL awk '!seen[$0]++' >> outfile.txt
```

run this another terminal; `echo msg="1" >> firewall.log`, output as below;

```
user@h$ tail -f firewall.log | sed -nu '/msg=/{s/.*msg=//;s/\S*=.*//;p}' | stdbuf -oL awk '!seen[$0]++' >> outfile.txt

user@host$ cat outfile.txt
1
```

run again same `echo msg="1" >> firewall.log`, output is not change;

After run this ; `echo msg="2" >> firewall.log`, output as below;

```
user@host$ tail -f firewall.log | sed -nu '/msg=/{s/.*msg=//;s/\S*=.*//;p}' | stdbuf -oL awk '!seen[$0]++' >> outfile.txt

user@host$ cat outfile.txt

1
2
```

Comment: Look at the sed command. It replaces everything

Comment: sed command get only after `msg=` in my env.   if firewall.log is like msg="yxyxyx", than the sed output is "yxyxyx".

Comment: yes and I would like store those values (just the uniques) in a txt file on-the-fly while the firewall.log populates with new records, so I choose tail -f. then I sed for the relevant part: yxyxyx from msg="yxyxyx", then awk for uniqe values but outfile is empty.

Comment: @tiborjan: could my ans. help you ?

Comment: unfortunatley not. the sed part itself "sed -nu '/msg=/{s/.*msg=//;s/\S*=.*//;p} >> outfile.txt" is working if I try this way, but I need the uniqe values only once. "yxyxyx" occurs 5 times "ababab" 14 times, I would like to have both only once on the output. Thank you.

Comment: @tiborjan do you use awk part?

Comment: cat /var/log/stormshield.log | sed -n '/msg=/{s/.*msg=//;s/\S*=.*//;p}' | awk '!seen[$0]++' >> outfile.txt . Outfile is empty.

Comment: could you provide sample data from stormshield.log?

Comment: @tiborjan I understood, I updated ans. could you try this;

Comment: @MustafaDOGRU saved me a lot of time. Thank you again.

Comment: @tiborjan: could you also upvote pls, thanks